# Stopping Bootstrap columns from listing vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking to make it so that when the screen gets smaller width-wise, instead of the columns in my row stacking vertically they shrink to fit the screen.

Currently I have this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div class="col-lg-4 headerBlock">
        <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-code"></i>
        <br/>
        <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 1</kbd>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 headerBlock">
        <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-laptop"></i>
        <br />
        <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 2</kbd>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 headerBlock">
        <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-coffee"></i>
        <br />
        <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 3</kbd>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I stop the columns from automatically stacking when the size of the screen reaches a minimum size and instead shrink them to fit the screen?

Comment: height-wise ? or you mean width ?

Comment: sorry, yes I did mean width. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can be more specific with the classes according to the size of the screen and the mediaquerys that bootstrap provides.

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f6a511uh/1/):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <div class="col-xs-4 headerBlock">
            <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-code"></i>
            <br/>
            <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 1</kbd>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 headerBlock">
            <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-laptop"></i>
            <br />
            <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 2</kbd>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 headerBlock">
            <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-coffee"></i>
            <br />
            <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 3</kbd>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify how wide each element should be, or specify how wide all the elements should be.

The documentation states, you have to wrap the `row` in a `container`, Then directly inside  `div.row` you start defining your divs.
`<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">` this isn't necessary,unless it's intended ?

So using the these :

**col-lg** is for large screens hence(lg)

**col-md** is for medium screens hence(md)

**col-sm** is for small/medium  screens hence(sm)

**col-xs** is for extra small screens hence(xs)

we can define our layout.

Now in your case you want all three elements to always stay in the middle, you can just go by specifying `col-xs-4` to all of them.

```css
.headerBlock{
  text-align: center;/* to center the inline elements */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4 headerBlock">
         <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-code"></i>
         <br/>
         <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 1</kbd>
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-4 headerBlock">
         <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-laptop"></i>
         <br />
         <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 2</kbd>
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-4 headerBlock">
         <i class="headericon blackicon img-responsive fa fa-coffee"></i>
         <br />
         <kbd class="headingkbd">Heading 3</kbd>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or `class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"` Only here you're being explicit.